# How to change the port of prometheus?

Tags: docker, prometheus

## I am going to run prometheus in a container, I want to change the port of the container that running prometheus.

I build a custom prometheus image base on the official prometheus image:

```
FROM prom/prometheus

COPY prometheus.yml /etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
```

and add the custom prometheus image to my Compose YAML file:

```
services: 
  ...
  prometheus:
    image: my_prometheus_image
    ports: 
      - "9090:9090"        # <—— change it to numbers that other than 9090 will result in an error
    networks:
      - nat
```

my problem is: when I specify `"9090:9090"`, I can browse to `http://localhost:9090` and see it works fine,
but when I change it to `"9091:9091"` then browse to `http://localhost:9091` will see an error.

In the [the official prometheus image's Dockerfile](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/main/Dockerfile), it has `EXPOSE     9090`, but the [Dockerfile reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose) says:

> Regardless of the `EXPOSE` settings, you can override them at runtime by using the `-p` flag.

so I thought `ports` in the Compose YAML file can also override it.

so, Can the port only be `9090`?  Is there any way to change it?

Comment: How is this related to programming?

Comment: Ah. I think there is a misunderstanding about the `ports`-setting in a compose file. The first number is the host port; the second number is the container-port. The container-port cannot be changed without reconfiguring the application; the host-port can be. So if we want to access prometheus on port, say, `1337` locally, we would use `- "1337:9090"`. For more details, see the [corresponding documentation at `docs.docker.com`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#short-syntax-1).

Comment: The _second_ port number must match the port number the process inside the container is using, but the two port numbers don't need to match.

Comment: @DavidMaze thanks! but how do we know "the port number the process inside the container is using"? I go to [the official prometheus image's Dockerfile](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/main/Dockerfile) and see it has `EXPOSE     9090` inside, is this the right place? Does it mean that we can only use `9090` as the container-port?

Comment: Fundamentally, yes, though it depends on what exactly is in the container (you can only use port 5432 as the second port number for a `postgres` container, 6379 for `redis`, and so on).

Comment: @Turing85 Thanks! "The container-port cannot be changed without reconfiguring the application", where to reconfigure the application to change the container-port? I go to [the official prometheus image's Dockerfile](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/main/Dockerfile)  and see it has EXPOSE     9090 inside, is this the right place?

Comment: I recommend reading the [relevant documentation (`docs.docker.com`)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose). It states that: "*The `EXPOSE` instruction does not actually publish the port. It functions as a type of documentation between the person who builds the image and the person who runs the container, about which ports are intended to be published. To actually publish the port when running the container, use the `-p` flag on `docker run` to publish and map one or more ports, or the `-P` flag to publish all exposed ports and map them to high-order ports.*"

Comment: To actually change the port the service is running on, we need to reconfigure the service. Whether - and if, how - this is possible depends on the application running in the container.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can;

```
ANY_PORT_NUMBER:9090
```

basically

```
EXTERNAL_PORT:CONTAINER_PORT
```

Examples:

```
3100:9090
5431:9090
8976:9090
3210:9090
```

Some useful links:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7JFJz9peYmY
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6by0pCRQdsI

note: before asking your questions you should search web with basic search queries : )

Comment: Thanks! but I am wondering why the `CONTAINER_PORT` can only be `9090`? Is there any way to change the `CONTAINER_PORT` to, say `3100:9091`, just curious on it.